# Error deploying Ruby On Rails over CentOS with Apache2 and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, passenger

I am new on Ruby on Rails and after i have finished my first project and trying to deploy it i found a bunch of error that I do not understand.

```
0   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `gem_original_require'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `require'
2   /var/www/fabiolaalvaradoservices.com/public_html/config/application.rb  3   
3   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `gem_original_require'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `require'
5   /var/www/fabiolaalvaradoservices.com/public_html/config/environment.rb  2   
6   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `gem_original_require'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  31  in `require'
8   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 222 in `preload_application'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 181 in `initialize_server'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in `report_app_init_status'
11  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 174 in `initialize_server'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in `start_synchronously'
13  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
14  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 149 in `start'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 219 in `spawn_rails_application'
16  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in `lookup_or_add'
17  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 214 in `spawn_rails_application'
18  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `synchronize'
19  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
20  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 213 in `spawn_rails_application'
21  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 132 in `spawn_application'
22  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
23  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `__send__'
24  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `server_main_loop'
25  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
26  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99
```

Please, I need some one who can give me a hint what do I need to fix.

By the way I am using **CentOS** + **Apache2** + **Passenger**.

**config/application.rb file**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Demo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

**Configuration for Development and Production**

Development Settings 

Ruby version: 1.9.3p392 

Rails version: 4.0.0.rc2

Production Settings 

Ruby version: 1.9.3p484 

Rails version: 4.0.2

**Here my gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: can you show us your config/application.rb file?

Comment: dear beck03076, above the updated post including the config/application.rb file

Comment: Which ruby version were you using in development? and which version of rails?

Comment: I have included the settings for Ruby and Rails for both Production and Development environment.

Comment: It looks like you might have the wrong ruby version on the machine you're trying to deploy to. what does ruby -v tell you?

Comment: And the rails version that you're using is going to be specified in your gem file. So unless in that gem file you specified development and production groups and set them as intentionally different versions, it's going to be set to just 1 rails version

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv on the centos production machine?

Comment: I am getting the version number updated above. I just ran the ruby -v from both Production and Development console and I just copied the the info above.

Comment: Is there any way that I can specify the ruby version from my source project that will match the production environment?

Comment: I have added to my post the gemfile, please take a look maybe there is the problem.

Comment: I'll be a little bit before I can get back to respond. Just wanted to make a quick response letting you know. Quick answer is you use rvm to set your ruby version. look up rvm commands. Something like running the command rvm use 1.9.3-p484. You'll have to use rvm to set the versions. and you'll want to, because of updates and security patches and so forth. So you'll probably have different versions. be back to see where youre at

Comment: and you run ruby -v in terminal, not in your ruby console

Comment: @Chale, Did you figure it out. Was my previous comment helpful? Where are you at on this

Comment: I have tried every suggestion posted here with no success. I am considering switch to Ubuntu instead of CentOS. What I have found is that CentOS has old libraries compared with others LINUX version, maybe that is my main problem.